# Corner modelling technique

Tags: modeling

I am making a bracket for three rods in blender and I figured out it is harder than it seems.

I managed to make this by painstakingly placing each vertex in the correct position and I am wondering, is there a better way to do this.

I included an image to show what I am talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can also use the Bevel tool.

1. Take the default cube, and extrude three sides
2. Select the outer edges and bevel them (e.g. Bevel modifier)
3. Remove double vertices (e.g. Weld modifier)

[image]

<sup>[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC9FC.png) shows which edges to bevel</sup>

Comment: That was an 'Oh Wow' moment for me.

Comment: Thanks. Never been more proud about cutting corners :).

Comment: yeah its nice if you want that edge round like that...

Answer (score 23):

**using mirror modifier bisect property**

1) create a cylinder
[image: create a cylinder]

2) add a plane and rotate it on the Y 45deg

[image]

3) add mirror modifier, check the X axis and X bisect. (also check clipping)

[image]

4) Duplicate the original plane and rotate it on the Z 90deg

[image]

5) add another mirror modifier and again check the X axis and X bisect (with clipping)

[image]

6) TADA! you can solidify and bevel the result.

[image]

Comment: Love this approach, it's so simple :).

Comment: Brilliant. Great use of the new features in the modifier.

Comment: awesome thanks i didnt know that was posible

Answer (score 5):

first create a cylinder,

[image]
then duplicate it twice, rotate two of them to 90 degress in the x and y axis, but depending the position you will put them,
[image]
then 
enable snap during transform in increment, then go to right,top view to move each one (in this case only 2 of them) them precisely in the grid,
[image]
then select one and hide it, then select the other and perform a boolean in edit mode, select union option, then start doing some clean up of faces,edges, and merge vertices by distance if necessary...
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
then unhide the other cylinder, and do the same steps...
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Final Result
[image]

Comment: Hm, well that's one way, I guess